# Cannot read property 'email' of null at HTMLDocument (Firebase)

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I try to run this firebase function but it returns null every single time

```
function gen_tell_name() {
      $(document).ready(function() {
        var db = firebase.firestore();
        var email = firebase.auth().currentUser.email;
        var docRef = db.collection("users").doc(email);
        docRef.get().then(function(doc) {
                $("#teller-name").append(doc.data().Name);
         });
      });
    };
```

I think I need some way to run it after all firebase functions are done but I do not know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the firebase [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users):

> You can also get the currently signed-in user by using the currentUser
>   property. If a user isn't signed in, currentUser is null

In your case, `currentUser` is `null` so you can't access the email address (on `null`)

```
var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
if (user) {
  // User is signed in.
  // Continue here
} else {
  // No user is signed in.
}
```

The recommended way to get the current user:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in.
    // you can safely access the users properties 
  } else {
    // No user is signed in.
  }
});
```