# Firestore: getDocs, getDoc; Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using firestore to store some data in two collections ("users" and "requests"). I have some functions in my javascript code that allow me to read and write the data in the database, and they work fine. However, when I use the same methods in the following code, I get two errors:

- Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'email')
  at HTMLDocument
- Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener') at Array.forEach () at He.forEach.

I've tried several options but they don't work and I'm very confused, because the code I use to access the data works fine in other parts of the program.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

    const user = auth.currentUser;

    getDocs(collection(db, "requests")).then(querySnapshot => {
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            document.getElementById(doc.id).addEventListener('click', function() {
                openAcceptModal();
            })
        })  
    })
    getDoc(doc(db, "users", user.email)).then(docSnap => {
        if (docSnap.exists()) {
            const uEmail = docSnap.get("email");
            const uName = docSnap.get("name");
            const uPost = docSnap.get("post");
            const uRating = docSnap.get("rating");
            const uTeam = docSnap.get("team");
            console.log(uEmail,uName,uPost,uRating,uTeam);
        }
    })
})
```

Does anybody have any idea of what's wrong with this?

Answer (score 0):

The First error “Cannot read properties of null (reading 'email') at HTMLDocument” is mainly caused if the current user is not signed in and it will take the null value, so  the user will not be able to access the ‘email’. You need to check whether the user is signed in or not, you can refer to the [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57418597/15774176) where an example has been provided.

The second error “Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')”  is mainly resolved by checking the variable before adding an event listener. You can refer to the [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67856104/15774176) where the issue has been resolved by the Rob.

Comment: Thanks @Divyani Yadav. I know the problem has to do with timing, because if I insert the function within a setTimeout instruction it works. But what I'm looking for is not so much to check wheather some variable is null or undefined as to delay the code in order to fix it. I tried the same code within document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(), but didn't work either.

Comment: @MountVesubio try doing this once for error1: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62449586/15774176 error2: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67856104/15774176 Is it helpful?

Comment: Apparently it solves the second problem, but not the first. I have my script tag inmediately above the </body> but adding "async" does not solve the error (Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'email')
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous>)

Comment: @MountVesubio can you refer this link: https://idiallo.com/javascript/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-of-null Is it helpful?

Comment: @MountVesubio Is issue resolved?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I don't know why user.email is null. The user is logged in, so its email should be defined. If I delay the code with a setTimeout, it works.

Comment: In any case, what I need is some code that executes AFTER user.email is defined, not one code that only checks if user.email is null or undefined. To check if the variable is null or undefined is useful to avoid the error, but does not help me to do what I need.